# Angular a tag download inconsistent file format

Tags: angular

I am using angular and trying to download file using the file path given by the backend server.

Here is the sample response from the server.

```
resources/sample_20190510164853106.xlsx
```

which is an object so I converted it to string using JSON.stringify and insert the filepath in href of my a tag using this code

html file

```
<button style="width:150px" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
 (click)="exportExcel()">Save Excel</button>

<a id="excelLink" [(href)]="filePath" [download]="fileName"></a>
```

ts file

```
filePath: string = "";
element: HTMLElement;

  exportExcel() {
    this.uploadService.saveToExcel().subscribe(res => {
      this.filePath = JSON.stringify(res.data)
      /* JSON.stringify(res.data).replace(/"/g,"") */
      this.element = document.getElementById('excelLink') as HTMLElement;
      this.element.click();
    })
  }
```

JSON stringify gives me "resources/sample_20190510164853106.xlsx" so I thought I just need to remove the double quotes hence the commented replace function but still to no avail. The file sometimes become html or json instead of xlsx when I click the "Save Excel" button.

[image]